# Applying Leibniz Integral Rule to Constant Limits of Integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, leibniz-integral-rule

Using the Leibniz integral rule given here, [Leibniz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule%3E), it seems that for any arbitrary multivariable function $f(x,y)$, we have:
$$ \int_a^b \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y) \ dx = \frac{d}{dy} \left(\int_a^b f(x,y) \ dx \right)  $$
Is that really always true? I feel like there must be some necessary conditions on $f$ to make that statement valid - like continuity of the function, it's partials, differentiability, etc. - but I am not quite certain. My question is what exactly are these conditions or is it simply always valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not always true. Take for example $$f(x,y)=\text{sgn}(x-y).$$

Comment: So do we just need the function and its partials to be continuous over the domain of integration?

Comment: I don't know the weakest conditions. At least $f$ being $\mathcal C^1([a,b])$ is enough. @joseph

Comment: So then if you wanted to apply this twice (to deal with a second partial derivative on the interior of the integral), $f$ being $C^2([a,b])$ would be sufficient?

Comment: my previous answer already answer to your last question.